# WPF threw exception after using dotfuscator?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, dotfuscator

I'm using dotfuscator 4.12 to encrypt exe and dll in my application!

But after encrypting, I run my app and it was crashed with the follow call stack

```
Set connectionId threw an exception./n Stack Trace =    at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)

at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)

at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)

at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)

at DVRServerInterface.MainWindow.InitializeComponent()

at DVRServerInterface.MainWindow..ctor()
```

My application is using WPF, it has 13 projects include C++ and C# projects, all of them are using .Net Framework 4.0. And I have checked all encryptation's options when use dotfuscator.

Someone can help me to fix it?

Many Thanks,

T&T

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's caused by Dotfuscator.

Make sure you've got all the dependencies\references in the right place. Normally when you get "Set connectionId threw an exception" exception, you also have an InnerException that should tell you what references are missing.

When you catch an exception, log the details of the InnerException:

```
try
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //ex.InnerException.Message and other exception details are accessible here, so just log them somewhere to see what's going on, but it can be null too so check for that first
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how to catch that InnerException?

Comment: It's a property on the normal exception you catch (called InnerException)

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how to get InnerException details

Comment: Thank you! I will try and let you know the result soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's pretty common that an application stops to work properly after obfuscating.

If you are using an obfuscator then you want to obfuscate as much code as possible, but sometimes you have to disable some options in the obfuscator, for unfortune.

Usually, when out team faces such an issue, we use binary search to find the issue)))

We turn off a half of checkboxes in the obfuscator tool and then try to launch it and catch the exception at the same step in a program.
This process continues until you understand what option on which module causes the effect. Most of the time the cause of such a behavior is pruning or obfuscating itself.